# Tuareg mode: «Buffer x.ml has no process»

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

I’m quite new to tuareg-mode so I don’t know how to fix «Buffer x.ml has no process» problem. As far as I can see it skips syntax checks, etc. because of this. I don’t do anything but just opening my x.ml file which loads tuareg. Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: You need to show your configuration, run emacs with `--debug-init`, and show the output of *Messages* buffer. As far as I understand, this message is not from `tuareg-mode`, since it doesn't have any processes and doesn't make syntax checks. Looks like that you're talking about `merlin-mode`

Comment: Ok, I’ll check. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is error message of merlin mode.
2. Install and set up merlin.

Thanks @ivg